# Visual Studio 2015 - less reference path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, less

My company recently moved our newest projects from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015 and now I have a small issue. In 2013 I had WebEssentials plugin (by the way: slow as hell [~5.5s]) that was taking care of less compilation, now there's gulp [~0.5s] that handles building process and here's the problem: I have a lot of nested imports and while writing code I don't have intelliSense for variables and mixins, I know that VS can't magically figure out how my structure is made, but is there any way that I could pass a root reference file or any other reference to use helpers with mixins and variables names?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly enough, because I never had to do that before and didn't even knew how to correctly name my issue, yet, I figured out the solution for javascript files and luckily it works the same for less files, so all I have to do is just to add the first line that points to core less file as for example

```
/// <reference path="../../wrapper.less" />
```